# Spring Boot App no longer logging to eclipse(STS) console

Tags: java, eclipse, spring-boot, slf4j, spring-tool-suite

I've just combined several rest service projects into a a gradle multi-project.  In order to do this I created a new workspace and imported everything after configuring my build.gradle for each project.

Most of the applications were able to start correctly using run as spring boot application however now in this new workspace nothing is being logged to the console.  I was able to see the logs before in my old workspace.

I am using  `compile('org.projectlombok:lombok:1.16.6')` in my parent build.gradle with the @Slf4j annotation which generates a logger field to write to the log in my classes.

Everything seemed to just work before and now I'm not sure what happened that is preventing logging.

Any help is appreciated

-Thanks

Comment: Not sure to be honest. Did you install Lombok Eclipse support and does it appear to be working correctly (e.g. when you refer the logger field in your code, does Eclipse show any compile errors). If yes, you can try putting a breakpoint into a call to the logger and try and step into it to try to debug why its not logging. Slf4j may somehow be configured to drop your logs, or redirectt its output elsewhere.

Comment: Through more investigating I've noticed that nothing from Java is being logged I can create a trivial hello world app that just does sysout and I don't see anything in the eclipse or cmd logs.  I've opened another question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43873187/java-version-output-opens-a-new-window-and-promptly-closes-it?noredirect=1#comment74786149_43873187) where I'm asking about this issue.  Even when I try `java -version` on the command line a second console pops up for a split second but I can't get the output.  This make me think that it is some sort of java conflict

Comment: What's your OS? Windows?

Comment: yes windows 7 I even tried a system  restore to no avail.

Comment: Not that familiar with Windows. I'm Unix/Linux guy myself. But maybe this helps: https://serverfault.com/questions/35116/what-is-the-difference-between-java-exe-and-javaw-exe There are some discussions there about certain ways of running JVM on windows making the output disapear.